# is it possible to add action.open url inside the body array in adaptive card?

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards, cortana-intelligence, adaptive-design, cortana-skills-kit

In my bot application i need to display a action.open Url button in-between the text.I need to Add Action.Open url inside the body tag of the json at the end of date as shown in the image and need to click the url link to do some actions.

[Adaptive Card Design Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4fgg.jpg)

is it possible to add the button in-between text or at the top of text inside the body tag.?

```js
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "color": "Warning",
            "text": "Company Name"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Meeting Details",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "FactSet",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "title": "Description",
                    "value": "xxx"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Key Note Speaker",
                    "value": "yyy"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Date :",
                    "value": "03/25/2019 12:30:00 PM"
                }
            ]
        },
       
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "size": "ExtraLarge",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "color": "Accent",
            "text": "**************"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Meeting Details",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "FactSet",
            "facts": [
                 {
                    "title": "Description",
                    "value": "xxx"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Key Note Speaker",
                    "value": "yyy"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Date :",
                    "value": "03/25/2019 12:30:00 PM"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "size": "ExtraLarge",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "color": "Accent",
            "text": "**************"
        }
    ],

     "actions": [
          {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "Add to Calender",
            "url": "http://adaptivecards.io"
            },
             {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": " Click here to add more Info ",
            "url": "http://adaptivecards.io"
            }
     ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the default location for buttons in AdaptiveCards is at the bottom of the card, and you are unable to change that. However, you can add an image styled how ever you'd like to the card with a selectAction attribute that will submit data associated with the action when the user clicks the image. For more details see the example AdaptiveCard JSON below and the AdaptiveCard Documentation for [Images](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Image.html) and [Select Actions](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Submit.html).

**Screenshot**

[image]

**JSON**

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Large",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "color": "Accent",
            "text": "Company Name"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "separator": true,
            "size": "Medium",
            "text": "Meeting Details"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Description:"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Keynote Speaker:"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Date:"
        },
        {
            "type": "Image",
            "selectAction": {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "data": "Meeting 1"
            },
            "url": "C:\\Users\\v-thdurn\\Developer\\Node\\Azure\\thdurn-all-channels-src\\resources\\button.png"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "separator": true,
            "size": "Medium",
            "text": "Meeting Details"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Description:"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Keynote Speaker:"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Date:"
        },
        {
            "type": "Image",
            "selectAction": {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "data": "Meeting 2"
            },
            "url": "C:\\Users\\v-thdurn\\Developer\\Node\\Azure\\thdurn-all-channels-src\\resources\\button.png"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you  tdurnford. I set local path to image URL for button, it is working when i tested in emulator. When i publish the channel image not available. Where i want to store the image.

Comment: You can either configure your project to serve static files or you can use a 3rd party provider like PhotoBucket or Imgur  to host your image for you.